# Poor graphics and behavior on Red Dead Redemption 2 on Steam

Tags: pc, red-dead-redemption-2, nvidia-geforce-experience

Just got a new PC with an Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060, 32 GB of Ram, 500 GB SSD, and 1 TB HHD, 12th Gen Intel I7 12 core, 25 MB cache, 2.1 to 4.9 GHz, Windows 11 OS.

I'm running this with a Samsung Odyssey G50A with G-Sync WQHD 32" Flay monitor with a response rate up to 165 Hz.

I set up the G-Sync to be enabled for Windows and full screen. I set resolution under PC for 2560 × 1440 (not sure why this isn't listed under the UHD, HD, SD options - that only lists 1080 resolutions). Also, I set the refresh rate to 144Hz (figured 165Hz was more than I needed for my setup).

When I play *RDR2* I am experiencing graphic bleeding (my character sitting down on another and occupying the same pixels), horse sometimes disappears and then instantly reappears in another location nearby like teleporting, glitching, and sputtering. I also keep getting prompted by the Nvidia desktop app that I could optimize the graphics by changing settings but I don't see anything more optimal for what I'm running with.

Today my screens turned all green when I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to exit full screen while playing the game.

Anything I can do to improve the graphics/behavior in *RDR2*?

Comment: Restarted PC and got my refresh rate options back

Comment: If the refresh rate issue has been resolved, I suggest editing that part out of your question, so answerers can concentrate on the remaining issue.

Comment: @galacticninja Done!

Comment: In-game glitches like your horse disappearing have nothing to do with your graphics setup. What you can try is lowering all settings, and then go through them one by one, restarting the game every time. And, just to be sure, you have up-to-date video card drivers, right?

Comment: @Joachim I ran system updates a couple of days ago and rebooted and there was a vast improvement. Just updated driver via Nvidia's GeForce experience to version 516.94. Will see if this helps. Thank you.